# Как реализовать дописывание знаков в определенной позиции при вводе текста в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Допустим я пишу 000000
И после каждого третьего знака должно автоматически проставляться "-", вот так: 000-000

Пробовал методом `Insert(3,"-")` в событии `TextChanged`, но что-то не получается, появляется исключение, да и если писать не один знак, то при каждом изменении будет дописываться лишние знаки: 000-------000

Это что же, надо еще прописать замену всех лишних "--" в реальном времени на одну "-" методом `Replace`? Это правильная логика моих действий? Или можно по-другому? А если будет не одна позиция с символом "-", а две или три: 00-00-00-00, то как применить `Replace` в этом случае? Или он заменит отдельно каждую последовательность двух тире "--" на одну во всех позициях без проблем?

Но в любом случае `Insert` на событии `TextChanged` не хочет работать...

Как быть?

P.S. я новичок

---

**UPD**

`Insert` заработал через событие `KeyDown`, но курсор перемещается в начало строки.

---

Исправил вот так.

```
 int a = ++ Text1.CaretIndex;
 Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Insert(3, "-");
 Text1.CaretIndex = a;
```

---

**UPD 2**

В общем я сделал так:
Кривовато, но работает (не без проблем)

```
    private void Text1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int a = ++Text1.CaretIndex + 1;
        Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Replace("-", "");
        Text1.CaretIndex = a;

        if (Text1.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Insert(3, "-");
            Text1.CaretIndex = a;                             
        }
        if (Text1.Text.Length >= 7)
        {
            Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Insert(7, "-");
            Text1.CaretIndex = a;
        }
```

Помогите допилить

Comment: А что, неужели тут нет такой простой вещи как шаблон ввода?

Comment: @Akina я не знаю, подскажите...

Comment: _Insert заработал через событие KeyDown, но курсор перемещается в начало строки_ - прежде чем заменять значение сохраняйте позицию курсора, а после замены значения восстанавливайте (`TextBox.CaretIndex`)

Comment: + AGS17 Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй воспользоваться [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx), судя по описанию проблемы это то что нужно и не нужно изобретать велосипед.

Для WPFT есть вот [это](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Это ж контрол WinForms

Comment: А как пользоваться вот "этим", и можно ли будет отформатировать четко под мои параметры, без всяких нижних подчеркиваний